# Laravel: different advertise for every new page

Tags: laravel

Lets say I want to show different advertises for every new page that a **guest user** visits on my site. Is there an out the box solution that I know if this is the first, second, third .. page that the user has visited.

If not intrinsic are there any packages that do the trick?

Comment: You can use a tracking cookie for this behaviour.

Comment: Due to many regulations I'd prefer not use cookies. Apparently one needs to get the users consent to use cookies.

Comment: You could also keep track with a Session. Most people would use tracking cookies though. Keep some relevant data in the session and change your advertisement output. The scope of the advertisements will be on your website only. If you want to go deeper I guess you can even save this behaviour in a database tied with an user for example.